# Summing Values of One Vector Conditional on Values of Another Vector

Tags: r, vector

For some context, I am trying to add up all of the home wins the Chicago Cubs have.  Thus, the W_L column refers to the wins ("W") and losses ("L").  Also, the H_A column refers to home games ("H") and away games ("A").

I am having trouble adding the total number of values "W" from one column when another column has a value of "H".  Below is the code I am trying to use.

```
setwd("blah blah blah")
br <- read.csv(file="Baseball-Reference.csv", h=T)

record <- function(){
wins <- sum(br$W_L[!is.na(br$W_L)] == "W")
losses <- sum(br$W_L[!is.na(br$W_L)] == "L")
wp <- round(wins/games, digits = 3)
home_wins <- if(br$H_A[!is.na(br$H_A)] == "H"){
    wins <- sum(br$W_L[!is.na(br$W_L)] == "W")}
}
```

If I run this I get a warning.

```
Warning message:
In if (br$H_A[!is.na(br$H_A)] == "H") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need the `if` statement? Perhaps this works as well:

```
home_wins <- with(br, sum(W_L == "W" & H_A == "H"))
home_wins
```

Or just a quick count, albeit without assigning the separate results to variables:

```
tt <- with(br, addmargins(table(W_L , H_A)))
tt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifelse` instead of `if`

The `ifelse` function performs elementwise conditional evaluation upon a vector:

Example:

```
x<-3
y<-c(1,2,3)
```

**ifelse**

```
ifelse(x==y,"good","bad")
    [1] "bad"  "bad"  "good"
```

**if**

```
if (x ==y) "good" else "bad"
[1] "bad"
Warning message:
In if (x == y) "good" else "bad" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```